# Why is sqoop trying to use SELECT WITH GRANT?

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata

I am trying to sqoop from a teradata database.

I used the following invocation:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:teradata://<<ip>>/database=<<dbname>>,LOGMECH=<<logmech>> --connection-manager "com.cloudera.connector.teradata.TeradataManager" --username <<user>> -P  --target-dir <<targetdir>> --query 'SELECT * FROM  <<source-db>>.<<source-table>> WHERE $CONDITIONS sample 10'  --split-by  <<fieldname>> --hive-import --hive-database <<hivedb-target>>  --hive-table <<hivetable-target>>
```

And getting the following error:

```
16/10/12 22:31:23 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.11] [Error 3523] [SQLState 42000] An owner referenced by user does not have SELECT WITH GRANT OPTION access to <<source-db>>.<<source-table>>
```

Can anyone help with this error?

It seems like sqoop is trying to delegate/assign access to the table.

The input database product is Teradata

The input database version is 14.10

The jdbc driver version is 15.0

Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `<<user>>` has `SELECT` permission on `<<sourcedb>>.<<sourcetable>>` which is likely a view in Teradata. The `<<sourcedb>>` requires a special `SELECT` privilege to be granted on the objects referenced in `<<sourcetable>>` or the database(s) containing those objects.

`GRANT SELECT ON <<ReferencedDB>>.<<ReferencedObject>> TO <<SourceDB>> WITH GRANT OPTION;`

OR

`GRANT SELECT ON <<ReferencedDB>> to <<SourceDB>> WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: Why the need to have the WITH GRANT OPTION? Why is the SELECT privilege insufficient in this instance?

Comment: `SELECT WITH GRANT` acts like a pass-through permission allowing a user to access an object which they have not been explicitly given permission to access and does not have implicit rights to the object.

Comment: The table I am querying is an actual table not a view. And I know I have SELECT access to it. Is that access insufficient?

Comment: I've found the same sqoop invocation works if I add -m1. Very odd

Answer (score 0):

You need to give select rights with grant option on the <>.

Follow this link
http://teradataforum.com/teradata/20040908_102929.htm

Comment: Why the need to have the WITH GRANT OPTION? Why is the SELECT privilege insufficient?